# How to import event Attendees

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to import a list of names and emails from an event, but I don't see any place in the Field Mappings for "Import Participants" that say anything about Name/Email or any contact information.

How or where do we import contacts from events?

(This is a CiviCRM install on WordPress)

Answer (score 2):

Import them as Contacts - on final step of import do 'add to a new group'

Find all Contacts in that Group and then add as participants to your event via the Actions button on the search results.